# How to Specify System.now() in Json while creating a record

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm creating a record in a test class that needs a specific LastModifiedDate, that date would be, today's date minus 365 days.
When I create the record, this is what the code looks like:

```
String OppJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Opportunity/500E0000002nH2fIAE"},"Id":"500E0000002nH2fIAE","LastModifiedDate":"2015-01-06T17:54:26.000+0000"}';
Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(OppJSON, Opportunity.class );
```

But I would like to instead of manually specify the datetime of LastModifiedDate to take today's date/time and substract 365 days. What would the syntax look like for this?
I know I can do this:

```
Datetime oneyearago = System.today().addDays(-365);
String value = String.valueOf(oneyearago);
```

but I don't know how to use that value string in my json.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you have the date in the correct format, inserting it in your JSON is trivial. Just concatenate the constant JSON string with your timestamp using the '+' operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a neater way to do it but you could just serialize the date into a string like so:

```
Datetime oneyearago = System.today().addDays(-365);
String jsonDatetime = JSON.serialize(oneyearago);
```

Which outputs the specified date in the correct format:

```
2015-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
```

In response to your comment:

```
String OppJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Opport‌​unity/500E0000002nH2fIAE"},"Id":"500E0000002nH2fIAE","LastModifiedDate":' + jsonDatetime + '}';

Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(OppJSON, Opportunity.class );
```

Updated with a string that works correctly, but really you should look into crop1645's approach as that is more aligned with unit testing best practices.

Comment: Davin, thanks for the quick response, now that I have the jsonDatetime how should I use it while I create the opportunity record:
String OppJSON = '{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Opportunity/500E0000002nH2fIAE"},"Id":"500E0000002nH2fIAE","LastModifiedDate":"2015-01-06T17:54:26.000+0000"}';
Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(OppJSON, Opportunity.class );
How do I replace this part: "LastModifiedDate":"2015-01-06T17:54:26.000+0000"}';
with the jsonDatetime string that you created? Thanks again.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it didn't like something, look this is the debug log:
System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('2' (code 50)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries.

Comment: Updated my answer (again).

Answer (score 2):

One way around this issue is to create testdata with whatever dates you want, including the current date and change the logic of your application to rely on a Utility class property:

```
Date todayDt {
    get {return todayDt == null ? Date.today() : todayDt;}
    set;
}
```

and everywhere in your PROD code when you need to reference "today", you don't use `Date.today()` but instead `Utility.todayDt`

Your testmethod can thus create testdata with audit field dates to whatever you want (from today onwards) and then before you execute test.StartTest(), do

```
Utility.todayDt = Date.today().addDays(180); // example - for creating testdata with audit dates 0...180 days in past
```

Your PROD code will think that "today" is 180 days from the real today but as long as all references to `Date.today()` are changed to the `Utility.todayDt`; everything works. Sort of a "back to the future"

Comment: hmm...that makes sense, I will try it and see if it works on my Dev Sandbox.
Thank you @crop1645!